# Access the last_error in failure method of Delayed Job Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, runtime-error, delayed-job, airbrake

Iam using delayed job in a rails application. I want to notify an error to airbake whenever a delayed job fails. I checked on [github](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and leant about the **failure** method.

I want to send the last_error attribute of failed delayed job to airbrake. Something like this:

```
class ParanoidNewsletterJob < NewsletterJob
   def perform

   end

   def failure
     Airbrake.notify(:message => self.last_error, :error_class => self.handler)
   end
 end
```

But it gives me the following runtime error:

```
undefined method `last_error' for #<struct ParanoidNewsletterJob>
```

**Please help me figure out how I can notify Airbrake the last_error of a failed delayed_job.**

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the job to the failure method, and then extract the last_error from the job. i.e.

```
def failure(job)
  Airbrake.notify(:message => job.last_error, :error_class => job.handler)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work fine

```
def failure(job)
 Airbrake.notify(:message => job.error, :error_class => job.error.class, :backtrace => job.error.backtrace)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve what you want:

1. A job specific method which only applies to the type of job you want by implementing the failure method with the **job** as the parameter. The job will contain **error** and **last_error**. And this is what other answers are about.
2. A global option where a plugin can be developed to apply it to any job type created. This is desired if all jobs need to be monitored. The plugin can be registered and perform actions around various events in the lifecycle of a job. For example, below is a plugin to update the last_error if we want to process it before storing to database

One example below:

```
require 'delayed_job'

class ErrorDelayedJobPlugin < Delayed::Plugin
  def self.update_last_error(event, job)
    begin
      unless job.last_error.nil?
        job.last_error = job.last_error.gsub("\u0000", '')  # Replace null byte
        job.last_error = job.last_error.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
      end
    rescue => e
    end
  end

  callbacks do |lifecycle|
    lifecycle.around(:failure) do |worker, job, *args, &block|
      update_last_error(:around_failure, job)
      block.call(worker, job)
    end
  end
end
```

Basically it will be called when any failure occurs for any job. For details on how this callback thing work, you can refer to [A plugin to update last_error in Delayed Job](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1511026455-A-plugin-to-update-last_error-in-Delayed-Job).